# Best practice to reduce the number of spark job started. Use union?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

With Spark, starting a job take a time.

For a complex workflow, it's possible to invoke a job in a loop.

But, we pay for each 'start'.

```
def test_loop(spark):
    all_datas = []
    for i in ['CZ12905K01', 'CZ12809WRH', 'CZ129086RP']:
        all_datas.extend(spark.sql(f"""
        select * from data where id=='{i}'
        """).collect())  # Star a job
    return all_datas
```

Sometime, it's possible to explode the loop to a big job, with 'union'.

```
def test_union(spark):
    full_request = None
    for i in ['CZ12905K01', 'CZ12809WRH' ,'CZ129086RP']:
        q = f"""
            select '{i}' ID,* from data where leh_be_lot_id=='{i}'
            """
        partial_df = spark.sql(q)
        if not full_request:
            full_request = partial_df
        else:
            full_request = full_request.union(partial_df)
    return full_request.collect() # Start a job
```

For clarity, my samples are elementary (I know, I can use `in (...)`) . The real requests will be more complex.

*It's a good idea ?*

With union approach, I can reduce drastically the number of jobs submitted, but with a more complex job.

Answer (score 0):

My tests show that:

- It's possible to union > 1000 request for a better performance
  For 950 requests with local[6]

  - With   0 union  : 1h53m
  - with  10 unions : 20m01s
  - with 100 unions : 7m12s
  - with 200 unions : 6m02s
  - with 500 unions : 6m25s
- Sometime, the union version must "broadcast big data", or generate an "Out of memory"

My final approach: set a level_of_union

- Merge some request, start the job, get the data
- continue the loop with another batch

```py
    def test_union(spark,level_of_union):
        full_request = None
        all_datas = []
        todo=['CZ12905K01', 'CZ12809WRH' ,'CZ129086RP']
        for idx,i in enumerate(todo):
            q = f"""
                select '{i}' ID,* from leh_be where leh_be_lot_id=='{i}'
                """
            partial_df = spark.sql(q)
            if not full_request:
                full_request = partial_df
            else:
                full_request = full_request.union(partial_df)
            if idx % level_of_union == level_of_union-1 or idx == len(todo)-1:
                all_datas.extend(full_request.collect()) # Start a job
                full_request=None
        return all_datas
```

Make a test to adjust the meta parameter : level_of_union